# How to install PHP7 on OS X El Capitan without Homebrew?

Tags: php, php-7

I am interested in using PHP7, but I am not a fan of using Homebrew since I am not 100% sure of what is happening on the back. I always like to go the official sources and get the downloads myself and install it following provided instructions; however, this has been quiet challenging for PHP.

I downloaded the php-7.0.7 from the php.net site, but I am not sure on how to go ahead and use/install it on my Mac. When I try to use a search engine for help, all I can find is how to install it using Homebrew.

I would appreciate any guidance that you can provide me beforehand :)

Comment: i used http://php-osx.liip.ch

Comment: Have you read the build instructions on php.net?

Comment: @Andrea I have read them. I am stuck where it  asks to compile php. An error is happening in relation with apsx.